# Creating dynamic web pages by embedding Prolog within (X)HTML

Tags: html, prolog

Is it possible to embed Prolog code inside (X)HTML tags, just like in PHP, ASP or JSP? I've taken a look at XSB and SWI-Prolog, but didn't find anything like that.

In ASP, for example, you can do something like this without a problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("Hello World!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

How to combine (X)HTML and Prolog in a similar manner?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [prospear](http://prospear.sourceforge.net/), it seems to be providing exactly what you want.

In general, few other people have had the same idea, google for "Prolog Server Pages".

Comment: You are correct. :-) That is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to install and configure Prosper? I've tried to install it on Debian with Apache using the guide on the Prosper website, but I just can't find the way to start the service. How do you run it after unzipping? I've also tried running it on Windows (there's also a `.exe` file), but without success.

Comment: @Luca Sorry, I've got no practical experience with Prosper.

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has a built in html generation scheme that's based on the slightly different idea of defining the DOM for the document as a Prolog data structure and generating the HTML from that (you can insert chunks of HTML if you have them already).

See

http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/

or

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%273.17%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/http.html%27%29%29